# Darksky Loop through one year of daily data - Datetime Error

Tags: python, darksky

I attempt to loop through daily weather data in 2019 using forecastiopy but the error keeps showing. Not sure what the problem is.

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
import json 
from forecastiopy import *
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import datetime

key = 'xxxxx'

city = [40.730610, -73.935242]
start = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)


for day in range(1,365):
    fio = ForecastIO.ForecastIO(key,
                        units=ForecastIO.ForecastIO.UNITS_SI,
                        lang=ForecastIO.ForecastIO.LANG_ENGLISH,
                        latitude=city[0], 
                        longitude=city[1],
                        time=start+datetime.timedelta(day))
    daily = FIODaily.FIODaily(fio)
    print ('Max Temperature', daily.get_day(day)['temperatureMax'])
    print ('Min Temperature:', daily.get_day(day)['temperatureMin'])
    print ('Precipitation Pobability:', daily.get_day(day)['precipProbability'])
    print ('Precipitation Intensity', daily.get_day(day)['precipIntensity'])
```

The error shown is below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ForecastIO.ForecastIO(key,
>     ...,
>     time=start+datetime.timedelta(day))
> ```

Here, the `time` argument is supposed to be a string that is directly mapped to the [Dark Sky API](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#time-machine-request):

> #### time
>
> Either be a UNIX time (that is, seconds since midnight
>   GMT on 1 Jan 1970) or a string formatted as follows:
>   `[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[HH]:[MM]:[SS][timezone]`. [...]

Therefore, you could format the `datetime` object using [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)

```
ForecastIO.ForecastIO(key,
    ...,
    time=(start+datetime.timedelta(day)).isoformat())
```